# Let G = (V, E) be an undirected graph in which the degree of each vertex is a multiple of 10 or of 15. Show that |E| is a multiple of 5.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let G = (V, E) be an undirected graph in which the degree of each vertex is a multiple of 10 or of 15. Show that |E| is a multiple of 5.

Not really sure how to even think this one out. I know there can be v-1 edges and every degree of a vertex implies an edge. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Prahlad; I didn't know that this lemma had a name.

Comment: More generally, if the degree of each vertex is a multiple of $t$ and $t$ is odd, then the number of edges is a multiple of $t$.

Answer (score 4):

(total # of edges) = $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{v\in V}$ (# of edges incident to  vertex $v$)